# ICM 2018 lecture videos

Tags: soft-question, online-resources, conferences, icm-2018

Is there a place to watch ICM 2018 plenary lectures (and other lectures if possible)?

Here is the official Youtube channel of the ICM but they don't seem to be posting the lectures.

https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCnMLdlOoLICBNcEzjMLOc7w

**Update:** The public lectures of Etienne Ghys, Cedric Villani, and Ingrid Daubechies are up!

Comment: It takes a few days to make a video.

Comment: Have you contacted the meeting organizers to ask their plans?

Comment: Of course there will be videos - in 10 days or so.

Comment: Well, last time in Seoul, the videos got uploaded the same night.

Comment: I believe Étienne Ghys' lecture was streaming

Comment: "streaming" does not mean it does not need post-production.

Comment: Live streaming of lectures is by now pretty common, so I don't see why they couldn't do it, even if the quality is not ideal.

Comment: At least the lecture by fields medalist Peter Scholze is already put online by his home university Bonn:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7xD_JIJj22Y

Comment: The _slides_ of L. Fargues's lecture are available on [his webpage](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~laurent.fargues/ICM.pdf).

Comment: By now, the Fields Medal lectures and Laudationes are online, but none of the plenary lectures.

Comment: The plenary talks are finally online.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Update 2018.09.22.**  Go to the website icm2018.org, and use the menu icon (three horizontal bars) to get a menu list that has ICM videos on it. That takes you to a YouTube channel which has some of the plenary and invited lecture videos being uploaded.  If there is a problem accessing or playing the videos please let me know, and I will relay the information.  Marcelo Viana says in an email that they are uploading the videos, but did not say when they would be done. I checked it out and saw some of the plenary lecture titles uploaded.  Enjoy! **End Update 2018.09.22.**

I will ask the organizers tomorrow.  However, I suspect from other things that the plenary and invited lectures will be given lower priority than the current output, as much is being done to popularize mathematics for Brazil.  My guess is that Mark Sapir is right, and that you will have to wait a few days for the lectures meant for specialists (non-public). As a second guess, I imagine they are preparing Portuguese translations, and that doing so within ten days will be an impressive feat.

** Update 2018.08.04 **

Marcelo Viana graciously offered a moment of his time; he says he hopes (with a pessimistic estimate) that the end of month will see the videos posted.  They have been working hard to make this Congress as paperless as possible (which on the whole is a good move, I think), and one of the tasks remaining is to update and post (a version of) the database of abstracts for use by the Congress members (and eventually the public, I imagine).

Gerhard "Impressive To Me, At Least" Paseman, 2018.08.03.

Comment: What does your nickname mean?

Comment: In this case, one meaning is that I am remarking that the feat of translating several technical lectures within a few days or weeks is one that is impressive to me.  Gerhard "Other Meanings May Also Ensue" Paseman, 2018.08.08.

Comment: icm2018.org redirects me to http://www.icm2018.org/portal/en/home and there is no menu icon there. Under the "News" there is a "ICM Videos" link to the Youtube channel. The latter contains lots of videos, including playlists of all plenary and prize lectures

Answer (score 5):

There are now several more videos of ICM talks available. I imagine that even more will be posted in the near future.

https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCnMLdlOoLICBNcEzjMLOc7w/videos

Comment: It looks to me like just the public lectures....

Comment: @DavidRoberts : new videos have been added :-)

Comment: @Watson yes, see https://thehighergeometer.wordpress.com/2018/09/13/more-icm2018-videos-online/